# Visual Studio 2015 Selenium WebDriver N Unit Parallel Testing

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I have set up the following  XML Schema for Parallel Testing N Unit Tests in Visual STudio 2015.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
 <RunConfiguration>
   <!-- 0 = As many processes as possible, limited by number of cores on machine,1 = Sequential (1 process),2-> Given number of processes up to limit by number of cores on machine-->
<MaxCpuCount>0</MaxCpuCount>
 <!-- <Execution parallelTestCount="0"></Execution>-->  
 </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

I have also enabled run settings folder in Test/Test Settings  but I am getting the following [image]

Can anyone please advise as to what I may be doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Based off previous comments I have updated my schema with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
   <!-- 0 = As many processes as possible, limited by number of cores on    machine,1 = Sequential (1 process),2-> Given number of processes up to limit by number of cores on machine-->
<MaxCpuCount>0</MaxCpuCount>
<TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   <!-- <Execution parallelTestCount="0"></Execution>-->  
   </RunConfiguration>
 </RunSettings>
```

I have confirmed that my .net framework is 4.5 for the TargetFrameworkVersion i have tried both x64 and x86. With that I am still getting the same output shown above. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

Go to DEVEXPRESS > Options... > Unit Testing, and then uncheck the "Enable Unit Tests Service" checkbox.

**Second solution:**

You can set TargetFrameworkVersion and  TargetFramework inside the RunConfiguration, example:

```
<TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Comment: The second solution yielded the exact same result. And the first one i don't understand where is Dev Express?

Comment: DevExpress is a kind of tool for Visual Studio. If you dont use, no problem. have you checked if the project .net framework version is equal or greater than 4.0? Your xml uses the extension .runsettings?

Comment: Please see update to question  based off what you said